# Comparator for recursivly nested structure

Tags: java

I do have a `List<Entry>` where each `Entry` has an attribute `parent` of type `Entry`.
I want them sorted like this (of course the order can not be used from the name - only from parent property):

```
(spaces do not matter)
E1
  E2
  E3
    E4
E5
```

```java
private record Entry(String name, Entry parent) {}

var e1 = new Entry("e1", null);
var e2 = new Entry("e2", e1);
var e3 = new Entry("e3", e1);
var e4 = new Entry("e4", e3);
var e5 = new Entry("e5", null);

List<Entry> entries = List.of(e5, e2, e3, e1, e4); // unsorted order
```

My idea was to unflatten this list to a Tree but a Tree does not help to get an Comparator. How could I use the structures to what I need to transform it, so that I can sort it with a Comparator?

Comment: What's the comparator for? A list could be generated by walking the tree appropriately.

Comment: Agreed. This isn't a sorting problem. It's a [traversal problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: I don't fully understand the ordering you want. Would E5, E1, E3, E4, E2 be valid?

Comment: @tgdavies no, E1 and E5 are "roots". I can accept any order E1, E5 or E5, E1 on the first level.

Comment: @DaveNewton that's a very simple approach I did not think about yet. +1

Comment: Then why not E3, E4, E2 on the second level?

Answer (score 0):

The most viable solution is to use a tree to get to a comparator -- by going through the tree and adding the index to each node.  Just add an `int` value to each tree node, and then number the entries as you go through them.